# Why is total stat block size of a directory twice of ls block size of a directory?

Tags: command-line, directory, programming, ls

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and would like to learn more Linux programming.

Each time I print `ls -l` and compare it again my own codes to add `st_blocks` of each file, the result is always stat block being twice of `ls` block size?

Is there a particular explanation for it?

---

In the command line:

```
$ ls -ls
total 28
4 ... test
20 ... test.c
4 ... test.txt
```

Program to sum non-'.' files:

```
$ myls
total 56
8 ... test
40 ... test.c
8 ... test.txt
```

Extract of code used in a loop:

```c
...
    ...
        if (dirName[0] != '.') {
            blocksize += buf.st_blocks;
    }
    return blocksize;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## stat

The block size used as the unit for `st_blocks` is always 512 bytes on systems that use the Linux kernel (which includes all GNU/Linux systems, such as Ubuntu). It's that size on most other Unix-like operating systems as well.

As [**Stephen Kitt explains**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521240/11938) in his answer to [Why is st_blocks always reported in 512-byte blocks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521151/why-is-st-blocks-always-reported-in-512-byte-blocks):

> The size of a block is implementation-specific. On Linux it’s always 512 bytes, for historical reasons; in particular, **it used to be the typical size of a disk sector**.

<sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

[stat(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man2/stat.2.html) lists the members of `struct stat`, which include:

```c
blkcnt_t  st_blocks;      /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
```

The `stat` command (see [stat(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/stat.1.html)) likewise uses a 512-byte block size. For example, as revealed by `ls -l`, on my system `/bin/nano` is 208480 bytes large, and the output of `stat /bin/nano` includes `Blocks: 408`.

---

## ls

`ls -l` prints file sizes in bytes by default, but `ls -s` prints them in 1024-byte blocks. There exist `ls` implementations for some Unix-like systems that default to 512-byte blocks, but both GNU ls (which provides `/bin/ls` in Ubuntu) and `busybox ls` (the other `ls` implementation in Ubuntu) default to 1024-byte blocks. You needn't pass `-k` for this behavior, even though it may be necessary on some other systems.

When printing file sizes in blocks, Ubuntu's `ls` command defaults to 1024-byte blocks because they are are more convenient. You can change this with `--block-size` if you like. In practice I believe the most popular approaches are:

- passing `-l` without `-s` to get a size in bytes (which is effectively a block size of 1)
- passing `-l` or `-s` with `-h` to print more human-readable sizes with unit labels
- passing `-s` and using the default of 1024 bytes

Some GNU utilities print 512-byte blocks when run in [a POSIX compatibility mode](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Non_002dGNU-Standards). `du` is a particularly obvious case; compare the output of `du /bin/nano` to that of `POSIXLY_CORRECT= du /bin/nano`. GNU ls also behaves this way when `-s` is passed, but the output with `-l` and not `-s`, as well as the output with `-h`, is unaffected. (The output with no options is of course also unaffected, since that doesn't print a size.)

In addition to supporting `--block-size`, GNU ls also respects some other environment variables, most notably `BLOCK_SIZE`. Unlike `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, this affects not only `ls -s` but also `ls -l` without `-s`. If for some reason you have `BLOCK_SIZE` set but don't want it used, and you want `ls -s` to use 1024-byte blocks instead, passing `-k` with `-s` will override it.

There are other ways to adjust this, and some subtlety is involved when more than one way is used simultaneously. For quick details, see the examples below and [ls(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ls.1.html) (`man ls`). For full details, read the [GNU coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/) (which should also be available locally: run `info coreutils`), especially section [2.3 Block size](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html#Block-size).

---

## `ls` examples

Here are some examples for controlling the unit size shown by `ls`.

`ls -l` prints sizes in bytes:

```
$ ls -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 208480 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

`ls -s` prints sizes in 1024-byte blocks:

```
$ ls -s /bin/nano
204 /bin/nano
```

Adding `-h` to either prints it in human-readable form:

```
$ ls -lh /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 204K Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ ls -sh /bin/nano
204K /bin/nano
```

Passing `-l` and `-s` prepends whatever `-s` would show by itself, rather than affecting the size columns produced by `-l`:

```
$ ls -ls /bin/nano
204 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 208480 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ ls -lsh /bin/nano
204K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 204K Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

Adding `-k` to the commands shown above with `-s` or `-l` doesn't change the output, because GNU ls already defaults to 2014-byte blocks with `-s`, and `-l` shows sizes in bytes and is unaffected by `-k`. However, `-k` has an effect in more complicated situations (see below).

Adding `--block-size=size-in-bytes` causes sizes to be printed in blocks of the specified size:

```
$ ls --block-size=256 -s /bin/nano
816 /bin/nano
$ ls --block-size=512 -s /bin/nano
408 /bin/nano
$ ls --block-size=1024 -s /bin/nano
204 /bin/nano
```

Unlike some other options, the `--block-size` option has this effect even on the size column produced by `ls -l` that would ordinarily be shown in bytes:

```
$ ls --block-size=256 -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 815 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ ls --block-size=512 -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 408 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ ls --block-size=1024 -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 204 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ ls -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 208480 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

`--block-size` is *not* overridden by `-k`, even if `-k` appears after it:

```
$ ls -s --block-size=256 -k /bin/nano
816 /bin/nano
$ ls -s -k --block-size=256 /bin/nano
816 /bin/nano
$ ls -l --block-size=256 -k /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 815 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ ls -l -k --block-size=256 /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 815 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

(My examples use powers of two, but the operand to `--block-size` needn't be a power of two. Also, `-s` and `-l` apparently use different rounding rules.)

Setting the `BLOCK_SIZE` environment variable has a similar effect to passing `--block-size`:

```
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls -s /bin/nano
816 /bin/nano
$ BLOCK_SIZE=512 ls -s /bin/nano
408 /bin/nano
$ BLOCK_SIZE=1024 ls -s /bin/nano
204 /bin/nano
```

```
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 815 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ BLOCK_SIZE=512 ls -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 408 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ BLOCK_SIZE=1024 ls -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 204 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

The difference in effect between the `--block-size` option and the  `BLOCK_SIZE` environment variable is that the `BLOCK_SIZE` environment variable is more often overridden by options. `-k` overrides `BLOCK_SIZE`:

```
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls -k -s /bin/nano
204 /bin/nano
```

That works with `-s`. But `-k` does not override `BLOCK_SIZE` for sizes displayed by `-l`, simply because (as detailed above) `-k` doesn't affect that:

```
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls -k -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 815 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls -kls /bin/nano
204 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 815 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

`--block-size` also overrides `BLOCK_SIZE`. Since `--block-size` affects both `-s` and `-l`, it overrides `BLOCK_SIZE` for both:

```
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls --block-size=512 -s /bin/nano
408 /bin/nano
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls --block-size=512 -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 408 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 ls --block-size=512 -ls /bin/nano
408 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 408 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

Setting the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable, even to the empty string, causes `ls -s` to use 512-byte blocks. The `-h`, `-k`, and `--block-size` options override this effect, producing their specified behavior instead. But unlike with `--block-size` and `BLOCK_SIZE`, `ls -l` still prints sizes in bytes.

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -s /bin/nano
408 /bin/nano
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -sh /bin/nano
204K /bin/nano
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -sk /bin/nano
204 /bin/nano
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls --block-size=256 -s /bin/nano
816 /bin/nano
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -l /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 208480 Feb 15  2017 /bin/nano
```

`BLOCK_SIZE` takes precedence over `POSIXLY_CORRECT`:

```
$ BLOCK_SIZE=256 POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -s /bin/nano
816 /bin/nano
```

Options that affect block size also of course take precedence over `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, since `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is merely changing the default block size. In particular, `-k` overrides `POSIXLY_CORRECT`:

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -s /bin/nano
408 /bin/nano
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -sk /bin/nano
204 /bin/nano
```

---

## `ls` - other options

I haven't shown all combinations of relevant options and environment variables.

Also, there are two more environment variables related to how GNU ls chooses block sizes:

- `BLOCKSIZE` (note that there's no underscore) behaves like `BLOCK_SIZE` for `ls -s` but not `ls -l`. It defers to `BLOCK_SIZE` when that is present.
- `LS_BLOCK_SIZE` behaves like `BLOCK_SIZE` but affects only `ls` but not `du` and `df`. If both `LS_BLOCK_SIZE` and `BLOCK_SIZE` are set, `LS_BLOCK_SIZE` is used.

These environment variables, like the others, take precedence over `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.

As mentioned above, see section [2.3 Block size](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html#Block-size) in the [GNU coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/) for more information, including details on those. This manual, which you can read from the command line by typing `info coreutils`, is much more detailed than the manpages for `ls` and other commands provided by coreutils.

Comment: Does that mean that the current ls -s blocks is adjusted to 1024B for readability over its default 512B? How can I run a code to call out this adjusted values?

Comment: @JinYuChan Yes, with GNU ls (`/bin/ls` in Ubuntu), `ls -s` uses 1024-byte block sizes by default, as if `-k` were passed. Other options and environment variables can override this. I've expanded my answer with details on that (and to fix a mistake about `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, which, contrary to what I had said, *does* affect `ls -s`, just not `ls -l`). I'm not sure what you mean by "run a code to call out this adjusted values". If you're asking how to *change* the block sizes `ls` uses, I've included that in my edit. Or are you asking if there is a way to make `ls` *print* the block sizes it uses?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It has helped me better understand how those values are being overriden. About the code portion, I wanted to write a C program that lets me call existing presets of 512B and 1024B without hard coding these values as the default block size may change in future.